# vim lost color in tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

Color scheme is `gruvbox`.

without tmux:

[image]

with tmux:

[image]

I tried

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

and

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

in `.tmux.conf`, none worked.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this unix.stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/568260/how-is-default-terminal-compared-to-tmux-terminal-overrides), you should also add this line in your *.tmux.conf*:

```bash
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",*-256color*:TC"
```

The accepted answer in the above link already has a good explanation of why this is the case, so I'll just summarize:

`default-terminal` is the configuration used by the terminals emulated inside tmux. `terminal-overrides` is the configuration used by tmux to communicate with the actual terminal it's running in (we'll call that the *parent* terminal). In your case, just setting `default-terminal` to use "screen256-color" isn't enough because tmux will still communicate with its parent terminal using a limited color set. Additionally setting `terminal-overrides` to also use "256 color" means that tmux will both use the expanded color set internally, and will tell its parent terminal to render in that expanded color set.

```bash
# Tell tmux to use 256-color internally
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
# Allow tmux to send 256-color to its "parent terminal", allowing
# the terminal to render colors in full.
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",*-256color*:TC"
```

The reason `tmux -2` works is because it does essentially the same thing. `man tmux` contains this description of the `-2` flag:

```
-2        Force tmux to assume the terminal supports 256 colours.
```

which is essentially what we did when setting `terminal-overrides`. Assuming the *parent* terminal supports 256 colors means tmux will send information to be rendered in the 256 color set instead of whatever limited color set it is defaulting to.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, the problem persists with these 2 configs for some reason..

Comment: Ah, I think I forgot a Vim config step. Try adding the line `set termguicolors` to your **vimrc** file (~/.vimrc for vim, ~/.config/nvim/init.vim for Neovim). Apparently that enables 24-bit color in Vim, but is off by default. See `:help termguicolors` for more info. Hopefully that works.

Comment: My vim becomes completely black and white after setting termguicolors.. Maybe I would just go with alias tmux='tmux -2'

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the same configuration that [@scupit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10029316/scupit) but without the `-` inside the quotation marks. I mean: `set -ga terminal-overrides ",*256col*:Tc"`

Answer (score 0):

Using `tmux -2` solves the problem. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Because it tells `tmux` to use 256 colors. Setting `default-terminal` just changes what the `TERM` variable will be set to; it doesn't make `tmux` *provide* a correspondingly color-rich terminal.